# Angular 12 mat-select renders options correctly, but can't select anything

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

first time posting. I'm using Angular 12.1 and I want to create a simple form component with a select input element. I'm using material, so I want to use `<mat-select>`.

I fetch data using a service, and store the response in an array, so i render the `<mat-option>`s using an `*ngFor`. Thing is, the options are rendering fine, which means data is being fetched and rendered correctly. However, when I open the dropdown to select an option, and click on one of them, nothing happens, and my form is invalid because that field is empty and required. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

component.hmtl:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h2>{{ "general.add" | translate }} {{ "general.distributionCenter" | translate }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form #form class="form col-md-10" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                    <mat-label>{{ "distributionCenters.name" | translate }}</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="dc.name" name="name" #name="ngModel" required>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="countriesReady === true">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                    <mat-label>{{ "general.country" | translate }}</mat-label>
                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" name="selectedCountry" required>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.value">
                        {{ 'countries.' + country.displayValue | translate }}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button class="w-100" color="primary">{{ "general.add" | translate }}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DistributionCenter } from 'src/app/interfaces/distribution-center';
import { ParamService } from 'src/app/services/params.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-distribution-center',
  templateUrl: './create-distribution-center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-distribution-center.component.scss']
})
export class CreateDistributionCenterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  countries: any;
  regions: any;
  communes: any;
  companies: any;

  dc: DistributionCenter = {
    name: '',
    address: '',
    regionId: '',
    communeId: '',
    companyId: '',
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
  }

  selectedCountry: any;
  countriesReady: boolean = false;
  countriesArray: { value: string; displayValue: string; }[] = [];

  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private paramService: ParamService
  ) {
    this.selectedCountry = null;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountries();
    console.log(this.countries);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getCountries();
    console.log(this.countries);
  }

  onSubmit(form: any): void{
    console.log(form.value);
    /* some logic */
  }

  getCountries(){
    this.paramService.getParams("country").subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.countries = res.params;
      this.countries.forEach(((c: any) => {
        this.countriesArray.push({
          value: c._id,
          displayValue: c.config.name.toLowerCase()
        })
      }));
      this.countriesReady = true;
    })
  }

  getTranslation = (param: string) => {
    return this.translate.instant(`countries.${param.toLowerCase()}`);
  }
}
```

Sorry if it's messy, I'm using a translate service. There is no relevant styling so I did not included it.

here is what happens:
[inputs render correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtlCY.png)
[options also render good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmyFC.png)
[this happens when i click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygw9I.png)

I've tried a lot of things, like fetching data with await/async, rendering directly, not using translate, using formGroup, etc. But still don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot add the directive ngForm to your form, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#access-the-overall-form-status): `<form #form ="ngForm">`